# mysql schema help for marketplace

Tags: php, mysql, database, schema

I am planning db schema for my next project(a marketplace),please check following...

```
tbl_users - id, email, password, created_at
countries - id, name
states - id, name, country_id
cities - id, name, state_id
areas - id, name, city_id
tbl_profiles - id, user_id, area_id, full_name, about, pic, email, phone, created_at
```

I am little confused after this, now i need to create 4-5 of profile_categories for example mechanics, painters, drycleaners, servants etc, but those will be divided into various `service_types` for example painters can be divided into - dry painter, oil painters, glass painters etc. So i have decided to come up with following structure...

```
tbl_mechanics - id, profile_id
tbl_mechanic_services - id, service_name
```

As its many to many relationship, i am using pivot table to join both

```
tbl_mechanic_service_pivot - id, mechanic_id, service_id
```

Now should i use same db structure for rest profile categories...

```
tbl_painters - id, profile_id
tbl_painter_services - id, service_name
tbl_painter_service_pivotv- id, painter_id, service_id
```

Is my above approach correct or can you suggest any better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just go this way  (If I got your goal correctly):

```
tbl_service_type: id, title
tbl_service_category: id, service_type_id, title
```

so if you have just 1 category per profile you can add new field `service_category_id` to your `tbl_profiles`

if every profile could be assigned to many categories you can create pivot table:

```
tbl_profile_categories: id, profile_id, service_category_id
```

Comment: You have got my idea perfectly and i like your suggestion, i am trying to make it efficient and fast, you think is this a better way to make it efficient?

Comment: Sure, that is classic way imho